# Customizing UMLClassDiagram in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, uml, class-diagram

I've created an UMLClassDiagram in Visual Studio 2012 and had some problems with its customization:

1. How do I make the qualified name to show only the class name without the entire namespace?
   It makes me expand for nothing the items with.
2. How can I remove the stereotypes to all of the classes at once?
   the `<<C# class>>` is just redundant for my needs.
3. Can I hide the operations and not just collapse it?
4. **THE MOST IMPORTANT** - how to do an auto arrange of the items?

I've tried to get answers from MSDN without success.
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff657806.aspx)

[image]

Comment: Regarding bullet 1 - it's just CTRL+A and right mouse button click - than hide qualified name

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2013 right click on class -> Hide Qualified Name from popup menu.  ;)